# arraylist nor getting store in hashmap

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, arraycollection

i m parsing xml in which particular designation contaion list of staff...
so while parsing i usee hashmap to store value.I continueously add staffdata in arraylist and when i found end element tag i put that arraylist object in HashMap and clear Arraylist to store next data.

but when i print hashmap ,i found only key in hashmap there is no arraylist at all...

if i dont clear arraylist after puting arraylist in hashmap then values are found in hashmap...but all values are come together..so i must have to clear arraylist after put arraylist in hash map...

```
**HERE IS MY CODE OF XML PARSING**

    package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class StaffXmlHandler extends DefaultHandler
{
    static int totalSection=0;
    static HashMap<String,ArrayList<Staff>> staffListWithDesignation=new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Staff>>();
    ArrayList<Staff> staffList=new ArrayList<Staff>();
    String designationName;

    public static HashMap<String,ArrayList<Staff>> getStaffListWithDesignation()
    {
        return staffListWithDesignation;
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException 
    {

        if(localName.equals("designation"))
        {   
                    designationName= attributes.getValue("name");
                System.out.println("=====================>>>>Designation="+designationName);
        }

        else if (localName.equals("staff"))
        {

            //System.out.println("======>>>>fetching data from staff");

            String employeeName = attributes.getValue("name");
            String employeeEmail=attributes.getValue("email");
            String employeePost=attributes.getValue("designation");
            String employeePhone=attributes.getValue("phone");

            Staff s=new Staff();
            s.setEmployeeName(employeeName);
            s.setEmployeeEmail(employeeEmail);
            s.setEmployeePhone(employeePhone);
            s.setEmployeePost(employeePost);
            staffList.add(s);

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException 
    {


        /** set value */
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("designation"))
        {


//          Staff[] s=new Staff[staffList.size()];
//          System.out.println("=========================="+designationName+"=======================");
//              for(int i=0;i<staffList.size();i++)
//              {
//                  System.out.println("=====Record "+(i+1)+"=====");
//                  s[i]=new Staff();
//                  s[i]=staffList.get(i);
//                  System.out.println("Name:"+s[i].getEmployeeName());
//                  System.out.println("email:"+s[i].getEmployeeEmail());
//                  
//                  
//              }
            ArrayList<Staff> temp=staffList;
            staffListWithDesignation.put(designationName, temp);

            staffList.clear();
            designationName=null;
        }


    }
    public void endDocument ()
    {
        System.out.println("==================End Element tag");

        Iterator<String> iterator =staffListWithDesignation.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) 
        {
        String key = (String) iterator.next();
        System.out.println("=====> " + key + "======" + StaffXmlHandler.staffListWithDesignation.get(key));
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)throws SAXException 
    {


    }
}
```

IN ABOVE CODE, IN COMMENTED LINE IF I CHECK TO SEE WHEATHER ARRAYLIST CONTAIN DAA OR NOT THEN IT SHOWS ME DATA BUT DONT KNOW WHY IT IS NOT STORE IN HASHMAP.....

PLS GIVE ME SOME SOLUTION...

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you put your list into the map create a new list. When you put your list into the map it is not copying it, so your further manipulation of the list (adding more stuff or clearing it) happens to the same list.

Comment: if i will create new arraylist after puting value in hashmap...that arraylist will not be accessable from other method,which add the data in arraylist

Comment: Ok it is hard to see that in the snippet above. Please tidy it up.

Comment: It still doesn't show enough info...paste whole class with correct formatting

Comment: hello buddy............thank you very much for your suggestion....i reinitialize arraylist object when i found stara element tag and my problem is solve...thank you thank you so mcuh.....i have wasted lots of time behind it.....GOD BLESS YOU...

Answer (score 1):

Like @kett_chup said, you should not re-use the arraylist after you put in in the map, you should allocate a new list, like so:

```
        staffListWithDesignation.put(designationName, staffList);
        staffList = new ArrayList<Staff>();

        designationName = null;
```

the staffList attribute will be accessible to the other methods, just like it was in the first place.